# Insert data into WPDB custom table

Tags: php, html, mysql, wordpress, insert

WPDB INSERT Error

I need help. I'm new to wordpress/php coding. I wrote a wpdb insert in a php template file stored in the theme folder. 
The purpose of the code is to insert form data into a custom table....see below.
Code written:

```
if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    //    global $wpdb;
    $cit1 = $_POST['cit1'];
    $cit2 = $_POST['cit2'];
    $cit3 = $_POST['cit3'];
    $cit_text = $_POST['cit_text'];

    $success = $wpdb -> insert(
        wp_citations,
            array(
                'cit_id' => null,
                'cit1' => $cit1,
                'cit2' => $cit2,
                'cit3' => $cit3,
                'cit_text' => $cit_text,
                'timestamp' => null
                ),
            array(
                '%s',
                '%s',
                '%s',
                '%s'
                )
    );
}
```

However, I used the print errors, `<?php $wpdb->print_error(); ?>`, function from reference codex and received this back as an error:

```
"SELECT * FROM wp_posts WHERE (post_type = 'page' AND post_status = 'publish') ORDER BY menu_order,wp_posts.post_title ASC"
```

The script I'm writing doesn't include any wp generated tables only custom tables I create.
I can only assume this is a hook or wp coded connection.

Has anyone ever seen this before? How do you bypass wp internal coding to use what is explicitly called in the new php file?

Not sure what to try.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code -

```
    if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
        global $wpdb;
        $cit1 = $_POST['cit1'];
        $cit2 = $_POST['cit2'];
        $cit3 = $_POST['cit3'];
        $cit_text = $_POST['cit_text'];
        $insert_array = array(
                                'cit_id' => NULL,
                                'cit1' => $cit1,
                                'cit2' => $cit2,
                                'cit3' => $cit3,
                                'cit_text' => $cit_text,
                                'timestamp' => NULL
                        );
        $success = $wpdb->insert(wp_citations,$insert_array);
            }
```

Also, 'timestamp' should not be NULL ideally. It should be current_timestamp in MySql database structure in Default column.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I made the update you recommended. The updated code did clear up the error. However, the form still doesn't pass the data to the wpdb. See the entire code. It is all in one custom theme page template.

Answer (score -2):

Please try below code, and always try to follow the same manner to track error easily. Hope this could help you -

```
<?php 
/* Template Name: Driver Monitor Page */
get_header(); 
?>
<?php
global $wpdb;
$result = $wpdb->get_results ("SELECT * FROM wp_ccr_info WHERE hoa_id = 4", ARRAY_A);
?>
<form method="GET" action="">
<label>Choose an Item to Citation: </label>
<select id="cit1" required>
<option value="">Select a CCR Option</option>
<?php
foreach($result as $row){
?>
 <option value="<?php echo $row[ccr_item]; ?>"><?php echo $row[ccr_item]; ?></option>
<?php 
}
?>
</select>
<br><br>
<label>Choose an Item to Citation 2: </label>
<select id="cit2">
<option value="">Select a CCR Option</option>
<?php
foreach($result as $row
?>
 <option value="<?php echo $row[ccr_item]; ?>"><?php echo $row[ccr_item]; ?></option>
<?php 
}
?>
</select>
<br><br>
<label>Choose an Item to Citation 3: </label>
<select id="cit3">
<option value="">Select a CCR Option</option>
<?php
foreach($result as $row
?>
 <option value="<?php echo $row[ccr_item]; ?>"><?php echo $row[ccr_item]; ?></option>
<?php 
}
?>
</select>
<br><br><br><br><br><br> <!-- why so many br tags ?-->

<textarea id="cit_text" maxlength="255" placeholder= "Explain any citation.">
</textarea>

<!-- add 2 more drop down menus
//add and text area
//add photos
-->
  <br><br><input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
<?php
    if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
        global $wpdb;
        $cit1 = $_POST['cit1'];
        $cit2 = $_POST['cit2'];
        $cit3 = $_POST['cit3'];
        $cit_text = $_POST['cit_text'];
        $insert_array = array(
                                'cit1' => $cit1,
                                'cit2' => $cit2,
                                'cit3' => $cit3,
                                'cit_text' => $cit_text
                                );
        $success = $wpdb->insert(wp_citations,$insert_array);
            }
?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Always avoid unnecessary spaces to avoid header already sent error. Happy coding!